# leveldb DeleteObsoleteFiles is private

Tags: c++, leveldb

Does anybody knows why DeleteObsoleteFiles member function is private in leveldb ? There are some situations when I need to free some diskspace and one of the ways to do it is to try to delete leveldb obsolete files. So can I make it public and call safely ?

Answer (score 1):

Files become 'obsolute' after compaction:

> `DeleteObsoleteFiles()` is called at the end of every
>   compaction and at the end of recovery.  It finds the names of all
>   files in the database.  It deletes all log files that are not the
>   current log file.  It deletes all table files that are not referenced
>   from some level and are not the output of an active compaction.

If you want to reduce disc space occupied you can run compaction

```
  // Compact the underlying storage for the key range [*begin,*end].
  // In particular, deleted and overwritten versions are discarded,
  // and the data is rearranged to reduce the cost of operations
  // needed to access the data.  This operation should typically only
  // be invoked by users who understand the underlying implementation.
  //
  // begin==NULL is treated as a key before all keys in the database.
  // end==NULL is treated as a key after all keys in the database.
  // Therefore the following call will compact the entire database:
  //    db->CompactRange(NULL, NULL);
  virtual void CompactRange(const Slice* begin, const Slice* end)
```

Comment: Thank you. I already found this feature. For manual squeeze CompactRange(NULL, NULL) can be called